Bing Maps API - I cannot view marker image/text but i can view title
I'm adding markers to my map after the event viewchangeend. Sometimes i can see my markers, other times i cant... i thought it might have been something to do with the map not fully rendered but when i added a title to my marker, i was able to see the title! i cannot see the red circle nor the marker's text.
I also tried to add a polyline to my marker layer just to make sure it is visible, and yes i can see the polyline too.
addMapMarker(latitude: number, longitude: number, index: number): 
Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin
{
// Check if it is safe to add markers to the map (i.e if both map's height and width 
are > 0)
// Otherwise start a timer to check when it is safe to add markers.
if (this.isMapSafe())
{
  const location = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(latitude, longitude);
  const pushPin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(location, {
    title: 'My Pin',
    text: 'lalala' + location.latitude + ' ' + location.longitude, 
    color:'red'
  });

  var center = this.map.getCenter();

    //Create array of locations
    var coords = [center, new Microsoft.Maps.Location(center.latitude + 1, center.longitude + 1)];

    //Create a polyline
    var line = new Microsoft.Maps.Polyline(coords, {
        strokeColor: 'red',
        strokeThickness: 3,
        strokeDashArray: [4, 4]
    });

  if ((pushPin) &&
      (this.mapMarkerLayer))
  {
    this.mapMarkerLayer.add(line);
    this.mapMarkerLayer.add(pushPin);
  }

  return pushPin;
}
else
{
  this.restartTimerToAddMarkers();
  return null;
}
}


Am I doing something wrong? Is there a reason why this happens and how can i fix it? Thank you in advance!

I'm not able to reproduce this. Here is the code block I used to test:
var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), {});

var layer = new Microsoft.Maps.Layer();
map.layers.insert(layer);

Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(map, 'viewchangeend', function () {    
      const pushpin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(map.getCenter(), {
        title: 'My Pin',
        text: 'lalala' + location.latitude + ' ' + location.longitude, 
        color:'red'
      });
      layer.add(pushpin);
});

Although I was surprised it worked as that title is very long. Here is a screenshot.


thank you for your answer. i mean i can still get that, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesnt! it's very inconsistent

I have yet to see it fail. Hard to debug with the little info we have. That said, if you are doing new development, have you considered using Azure Maps? Bing Maps is being retired and users are being directed to Azure Maps. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/maps/bing-maps/discontinued-services?msockid=191627acbb23650b07c93534ba316400
